# loads twice data when add Firebase data

Tags: android, firebase

I'm pulling data from the Firebase and adding data to the database. This process works smoothly. But when I add a room, the data is uploaded to RecyclerView once more, meaning there are two of the same RecyclerView. After the data is added, I just want the new data to be added, so that the old data will not be loaded again. Just want to add new data to the bottom of the old data.

```
public class RoomsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private List<Rooms> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RoomsAdapter mAdapter;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("0").child("Rooms");

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvRooms);
          mAdapter = new RoomsAdapter(roomList);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            getRoom();
}
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (id == R.id.add_rooms) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RoomsActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = RoomsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rooms_dialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Oda Ekle");
            dialogBuilder.setMessage("Eklemek istediğiniz odanın adını yazınız");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ekle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    final String roomsText =  edt.getText().toString();
                    final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("0");


                    rootRef.child("Rooms").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            dataSnapshot.getRef().child(roomsText).setValue(roomsText);

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
            dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("İptal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //pass
                }
            });
            AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
            b.show();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void getRoom() {

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

                    Rooms getdata = new Rooms(data);
                    roomList.add(getdata);

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AWW SNAP... Something is Wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Then update your recyclerView only when you receive a change in the singleValueEveny

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Post the code how you are adding items into the list

Comment: I updated the subject, thank you.

Comment: Are you using childEventListener as well??

Comment: Yes, I'm using.

Comment: post the code for same as well

Comment: What do you mean, what should I do?

Comment: because on childChange is called every time you change in the database, also valueEventListener is also get called

Comment: you need to check if the item is already added in the list or not before adding in it

Comment: I don't understand. could you please show me the code? @RahulKhurana

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to below and put a check using contains the method of ArrayList

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

            Rooms getdata = new Rooms(data);
            if (!roomList.contains(getdata)) {
                roomList.add(getdata);                
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AWW SNAP... Something is Wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: The same problem is happening again, adding the data to RecyclerView again.

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme post your code for childEventListener as well.

Comment: That's all the code is, I'm doing the process of adding and pulling data. There's no other code.

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme where are you calling getRoom() method??

Comment: Calling in the OnCreate method

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme have you tried adding multiple items?

Comment: No, I didn't try, it's okay to add items. Adds old data to RecyclerView as you add data

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme Yes for testing add multiple items in the firebase with different values so we can get a clear picture of the situation

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the list before adding in recyclerview just like that:-

private void getRoom() {

```
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             if(roomList.getSize() != 0){
                  roomList.clear(); 
              }

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

                Rooms getdata = new Rooms(data);
                roomList.add(getdata);

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AWW SNAP... Something is Wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```